# Для чего при импорте на Typescript используются фигурные скобки?

Tags: typescript, импорт

В чём различие в импорте на `TypeScript` между отсутствием фигурных скобок:

```
import Element1 from 'lib1';
```

и их использованием:

```
import { Element1 } from 'lib1';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Главное различие между ними заключается в том, что в 1 случае ты импортируешь **default** module и называешь его Element1, в данном случе название может быть любым, хоть ElementElement111. Второй случай позволяет импортировать привязанные имена экспрота. То бишь если у тебя есть 
`export const Element1 = 11` 
то вызов `import { Element1 } from 'lib1';` ипортирует только эту константу, а не весь модуль целиком

Comment: А как импортировать default модуль с тем же названием что в самом модуле? Просто `import 'lib1';` ? Или такой конструкции нету?

Comment: Такая конструкция есть и как написано в доках к ts о модулях https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html 
Ее не рекомендуется использовать

Comment: А для импорта с дефолтным названием нету конструкции?

Comment: В любом случаем помечаю ответ ответом, так как разъяснил то что я спрашивал.

Comment: Вот про импорт с дефолтной конструкции не знаю хорошего решения, но если верить Ts doc, то  import 'lib1'; это и есть решение. Так как ты ипимпортируешь все из файла lib1.
И да, рад помочь, успехов вам! =)